# Age of Empires 2: Age of Kings - Network Playability Issues

Tags: pc, age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings

I play Age of Kings (AOE 2) on my home LAN.  It runs ridiculously slow/choppy.  Both of the machines are well beyond the minimum requirements for the game to run, and my router is a fairly new Linksys with G wireless. (I get the lag with or without 1 or more of the machines using the wireless.)

Are there router or game settings I can use to fix this? Or is this a game that just doesn't work well with modern PC's?

Comment: Does this only happen on multiplayer? Or does it happen on single-player too?

Comment: Single player, it seems to run just fine on both of the machines.

Comment: Have you played any other games on the LAN?

Comment: I play all kinds of other things on the LAN, but mostly it's newer stuff than AoK.  For example, Age of Mythologies works fine.

Comment: I seem to remember having a similar issue now that I think about it. Have you patched the game?

Comment: I think I have it patched, do you know what the current version is?

Comment: @The Sasquatch: 2.0c, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Around Spring of 2006 I was trying to play via IP with a friend and we had all kinds of issues, then we tried out [hamachi](http://hamachi.en.softonic.com/) and it seemed to help out a lot. Not sure what all it did as I'm not good hardware/technical stuff, but it made that pretty easy. We were in the same apartment complex, but different buildings, and we each had our own ISP account and modems/routers.

Comment: I am ten feet from the person I am playing with.  We are either physically connected to the same router or connected on wireless in the same subnet with sequential IP's.  I am really hoping for a software or hardware setting to fix this issue instead of an entirely new networking application.

Comment: Fair enough, good luck man. Network issues always frustrate me!

Comment: I'm accepting this as it's as good of an answer as it looks like I am going to get.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As JustinP8 said above, Hamachi is a good idea, a guide on setting it up can be found [here](http://www.neoseeker.com/forums/40474/t1312410-hamachi-guide/). It works for either long distance or LAN parties.

Hope I've helped.

Answer (score 0):

For some older games like AOE2, you *can't* have a computer too far above the min requirements.  The game will have been written for older hardware and should perform better on an older computer.  Personally, it won't work on my XP machines, but it will work on some Win95's from the '90s in my basement.